# Consulta evento click jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

estoy aprendiendo, se algo de php y poco de jquery. Tengo que hacer algunos retoques a una aplicación de mi trabajo, desarrollada en cake php.
En este momento al clickear sobre un vínculo me lleva a una pantalla anterior .
Necesito darle ese mismo comprtamiento a un button que tengo mas abajo .
La línea original es :

```html
 <a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'preguntas')); ?>" class="reload_link productos">
          << Volver a Categorias
        </a>
```

Al clickear en << Volver a Categorias vuelve atras una pantalla .
Yo he hecho lo siguiente :

```html
  $("#btn-volver").click(function(e){
   e.preventdefault();  
   '<a href="<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'preguntas')); ?>" class="reload_link productos">';
  });
```

La idea es que no realice el comportamiento por defecto , que haga el llamado a la pagina del primer código. Alguna ayuda de como hacerlo con jquery a ver si puedo comprender ? Me faltó agregar que lo que hice no me funcionó ..
Gracias !!

Comment: si quieres que sea el mismo evento solo duplica el botón en el html... en donde quieres que aparesca...

Answer (score 2):

Puedes ahorrarte la funcion `click` de jquery y hacer esto :

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'preguntas')); ?>'">Redireccion con boton</button>
```

**EDICION**

Como necesitas que sea con el evento de `jquery`, te dejo esta opcion :

```
$("#btn-volver").click(function(e){
    window.location = "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'preguntas')); ?>";
});
```

Comment: Gracias amigo. El problema es que debo usar el boton con id = '#btn-volver' , el cual ya está asociado a un comportamiento que no puedo cambiar ( es usado por otras llamadas) . Por ello se me ocurrió usar jquery y cambiarle el comportamiento solo en esta instancia.

Comment: @look68 edite mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función que te comentan arriba

`window.location.href = "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'preguntas')); ?>";`

y colocarla dentro de tu función con una validación del evento que desees realizar. todo depende de que acción tomaras como evento de ejecución.

Comment: Gracias amigo x la ayuda . Parece no es muy simple este problema. Estoy estudiando cakephp ya que me pidieron reformar un comportamiento de una aplicación de mi trabajo que se fue armando en cake 1.3 y paso por varias manos, parece que en el medio alguien encriptó los php solo por probar y quedó asi. El tema es que tengo un boton "Volver" , que al hacer click vuelve 2 pantallas atras, y debería volver solo 1 . Probé con jquery haciendo un preventdefault a la función y tambien como me dices, pero sigue igual ..

Comment: Con jquery parece que quisiera , ya que hace como un intento pero por lo que voy aprendiendo es posible que ejecute el jquery pero inmediatamente busca el controller que está encriptado y finaliza con ese comportamiento. Puede ser ese el problema ? Gracias !!

Comment: Si. debes crear un controlador que simule ambos comportamientos y cambiar la ruta de ejecución. ya que no sabes cual es el funcionamiento de ese. te recomiendo que busques como modificar el controlador y en el peor de los casos como te comente crear uno nuevo con los comportamientos que desees y colocarlo en la ruta del controlador para su ejecución.

Answer (score 0):

También puedes utilizar el la propiedad `preventDefault();`

```
<script>
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // aca viene lo que tu quieras

});
</script>
```

la propiedad `preventdefault` evita que el evento se propague automáticamente sino que hará de ahí en adelante lo que tu coloques en esa función exclusivamente